# calling ajax request inside ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to call the jquery ajax inside another ajax success response.'request-status' response return correctly and '.table-responsive' div reloaded what I excepted.But in success response when I tried to call 'welcome-mail' I caught `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` .I tried as as

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'request-status',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {'id':user_id,'status':status,'comment':comment}, 
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //alert(data);
    $(".table-responsive").load(location.href + " .table-responsive");
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
            url: "welcome-mail",
            data: {'id':user_id},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
               alert(data);
        }
          });
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
 // alert('errror');

  },
});


Route
   Route::get('welcome-mail','travelerHome@welcomeMail');

controller
 public function welcomeMail(Request $request)
  {
    $request_data = $request->all();
   $id = $request_data['id'];  
    return response()->json();  
  }
```

Comment: so basically it's a syntax error right?

Comment: as per your edited question and associated code; i don't think you will get any syntax error. Please confirm.

Comment: It seems to me that you're adding an extra comma (like: 'error: func() { },') after the ending of your error method.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a bracket after success, but have an extra }); that doesn't belong there - it should be:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
               alert(data);  
         }
        });
```